# How to change HttpServletRequest.servletpath?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I'm using a few JSP-pages and one servlet.

Servlet doPost():

```
String userPath = request.getServletPath();
if (userPath.equals("/PageAdm")) {
     String username = request.getParameter("username");
     String password = request.getParameter("password");
     User userone = new User(username, password);
     request.setAttribute("user", user);
     RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("view/Page.jsp");
     view.forward(request, response);
} else if (userPath.equals("/Page")) {
     String username = request.getParameter("username");
     UsersService us = new UsersService();
     User user = us.getUserByUsername(username);
     request.setAttribute("user", user);
     RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("view/UserNameEdit.jsp");
     view.forward(request, response);
}
```

When I log in, I can change the username, but when I submit the form (click) to change it, the servletpath will still be "/PageAdm" but it has to be "/Page" so I can change my username. How can I change the servletpath so it will go to "/UserNameEdit"?

Comment: When you say "I click to change it" is that a form submit?

Comment: Yes, it is a form submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an action attribute to the form element to point to the correct path.

```
<form action="<c:url value="/MyServletPath/Page"/>" method="post">
```

Comment: That only changes the URL and I want to change to Servletpath.

Comment: Make the URL pattern for the servlet be: /MyServletPath/* and use request.getPathInfo()

Comment: I have to add the name of the jsp to the action on the form on the jsp with the same name.